AMD NIP backend зависает при запуске тестовых программ
Столкнулся с проблемой, при запуске программ для проверки работоспособности hip backend на amd платформе ноутбук через какого то время зависает и экран раз с 15 секунд погасает и вновь загорается.
Система:

laptop: HP 15s

CPU: AMD ryzen 5 3500u

GPU: integrated Vega 8, gfx902

RAM: 16gb

OS: Majaro Linux Arch.

Linux kernel: 6.5.13-7-MANJARO

HIP version: 6.0.32831
P.S. Программа падает на запуске банальной программы для суммы двух векторов. hipcc компилирует программу нормально.
ROCk module is loaded
=====================    
HSA System Attributes    
=====================    
Runtime Version:         1.1
System Timestamp Freq.:  1000.000000MHz
Sig. Max Wait Duration:  18446744073709551615 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) (timestamp count)
Machine Model:           LARGE                              
System Endianness:       LITTLE                             
Mwaitx:                  DISABLED
DMAbuf Support:          YES

==========               
HSA Agents               
==========               
*******                  
Agent 1                  
*******                  
  Name:                    AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
  Uuid:                    CPU-XX                             
  Marketing Name:          AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
  Vendor Name:             CPU                                
  Feature:                 None specified                     
  Profile:                 FULL_PROFILE                       
  Float Round Mode:        NEAR                               
  Max Queue Number:        0(0x0)                             
  Queue Min Size:          0(0x0)                             
  Queue Max Size:          0(0x0)                             
  Queue Type:              MULTI                              
  Node:                    0                                  
  Device Type:             CPU                                
  Cache Info:              
    L1:                      32768(0x8000) KB                   
  Chip ID:                 0(0x0)                             
  ASIC Revision:           0(0x0)                             
  Cacheline Size:          64(0x40)                           
  Max Clock Freq. (MHz):   2100                               
  BDFID:                   0                                  
  Internal Node ID:        0                                  
  Compute Unit:            8                                  
  SIMDs per CU:            0                                  
  Shader Engines:          0                                  
  Shader Arrs. per Eng.:   0                                  
  WatchPts on Addr. Ranges:1                                  
  Features:                None
  Pool Info:               
    Pool 1                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: FINE GRAINED        
      Size:                    14223580(0xd908dc) KB              
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       TRUE                               
    Pool 2                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: KERNARG, FINE GRAINED
      Size:                    14223580(0xd908dc) KB              
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       TRUE                               
    Pool 3                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: COARSE GRAINED      
      Size:                    14223580(0xd908dc) KB              
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       TRUE                               
  ISA Info:                
*******                  
Agent 2                  
*******                  
  Name:                    gfx902                             
  Uuid:                    GPU-XX                             
  Marketing Name:          AMD Radeon Vega 8 Graphics         
  Vendor Name:             AMD                                
  Feature:                 KERNEL_DISPATCH                    
  Profile:                 BASE_PROFILE                       
  Float Round Mode:        NEAR                               
  Max Queue Number:        128(0x80)                          
  Queue Min Size:          64(0x40)                           
  Queue Max Size:          131072(0x20000)                    
  Queue Type:              MULTI                              
  Node:                    1                                  
  Device Type:             GPU                                
  Cache Info:              
    L1:                      16(0x10) KB                        
    L2:                      1024(0x400) KB                     
  Chip ID:                 5592(0x15d8)                       
  ASIC Revision:           1(0x1)                             
  Cacheline Size:          64(0x40)                           
  Max Clock Freq. (MHz):   1200                               
  BDFID:                   1024                               
  Internal Node ID:        1                                  
  Compute Unit:            8                                  
  SIMDs per CU:            4                                  
  Shader Engines:          1                                  
  Shader Arrs. per Eng.:   1                                  
  WatchPts on Addr. Ranges:4                                  
  Coherent Host Access:    FALSE                              
  Features:                KERNEL_DISPATCH 
  Fast F16 Operation:      TRUE                               
  Wavefront Size:          64(0x40)                           
  Workgroup Max Size:      1024(0x400)                        
  Workgroup Max Size per Dimension:
    x                        1024(0x400)                        
    y                        1024(0x400)                        
    z                        1024(0x400)                        
  Max Waves Per CU:        40(0x28)                           
  Max Work-item Per CU:    2560(0xa00)                        
  Grid Max Size:           4294967295(0xffffffff)             
  Grid Max Size per Dimension:
    x                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
    y                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
    z                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
  Max fbarriers/Workgrp:   32                                 
  Packet Processor uCode:: 471                                
  SDMA engine uCode::      169                                
  IOMMU Support::          None                               
  Pool Info:               
    Pool 1                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: COARSE GRAINED      
      Size:                    2097152(0x200000) KB               
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       FALSE                              
    Pool 2                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: EXTENDED FINE GRAINED
      Size:                    2097152(0x200000) KB               
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       FALSE                              
    Pool 3                   
      Segment:                 GROUP                              
      Size:                    64(0x40) KB                        
      Allocatable:             FALSE                              
      Alloc Granule:           0KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         0KB                                
      Accessible by all:       FALSE                              
  ISA Info:                
    ISA 1                    
      Name:                    amdgcn-amd-amdhsa--gfx902:xnack+   
      Machine Models:          HSA_MACHINE_MODEL_LARGE            
      Profiles:                HSA_PROFILE_BASE                   
      Default Rounding Mode:   NEAR                               
      Default Rounding Mode:   NEAR                               
      Fast f16:                TRUE                               
      Workgroup Max Size:      1024(0x400)                        
      Workgroup Max Size per Dimension:
        x                        1024(0x400)                        
        y                        1024(0x400)                        
        z                        1024(0x400)                        
      Grid Max Size:           4294967295(0xffffffff)             
      Grid Max Size per Dimension:
        x                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
        y                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
        z                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
      FBarrier Max Size:       32                                 
*** Done ***             


